# RestApi security - how to restrict access

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I am planning to have an REST API in node.js , I want to make sure if the request comes from my web domain allow the request or reject it, how do I do this?

Basically I am trying to restrict access to the REST api by simple technique, any advise on this ?

Comment: Did you look at any tutorial on authentication? There are plenty out there.

Comment: You might want to checkout something like helmetjs. There’s an npm package for it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet

Answer (score 0):

If your criteria is only a particular user can access it or only signed user can access it,then you can do it with a helper function like below.

```
app.get('/api/users', checkuser, function(req, res) {
    UserModel.find(function(err, users) {
        if (!err)
            res.json(users);
        else
            console.log(err);
    });
});

function checkuser(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user != 'manoj') return res.json('message': 'you dont have permissions to access this url');
    next(); //if it is manoj then call the next() iterator function that will take u to the final callback(userFind)
};
```